# How to crop a video using react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

are there any library for react native to crop videos.
by cropping videos I mean showing some part of the video and rejecting other parts like we crop the images.
I am not talking about trimming the video because there is a difference between the word trim and crop

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a library for that, I've only found libraries for playing videos. So if you get stuck, [cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/video_manipulation_and_delivery) offers that utility through their API if you upload your video to their database

Example:

```
"https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/video/upload/w_300,h_200,c_crop/dog.mp4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://github.com/shahen94/react-native-video-processing?

Here's an example of how it would be used to crop:

```js
// portrait video output 720 x 1280
const aspectRatio =  640 / 480;
const outputWidth = video.width;
const outputHeight = parseInt(outputWidth * aspectRatio);
const options = {
   cropWidth: video.width,
   cropHeight: outputHeight,
   cropOffsetX: 0,
   cropOffsetY: parseInt(Math.abs((video.height - outputHeight) / 2)),
}
ProcessingManager.crop(video.uri, options).then(data => {
   console.log('success', data)
   // use video compress for 640 x 480
   ...
}).catch(error => {
   console.log('error', error)
})
```